# What is the main difference between class label prediction through Machine Learning and Conditional Label generation that can be done on raw data?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, feature-selection

I have understood that machine learning helps us to classify various instances using the labeled data, but why do we need machine learning when we obtain the same results through generating labels by directly asserting some parameters on the feature.

For example, let us use Air Quality dataset which has various features such as CO(GT), O$_3$, CO gases which are associated with certain units, in case of unknown or unidentified class label I can set certain parameters based on general assumptions of air quality index on raw data using excel operations and generate a class label but why do I need to train any kind of classifier for the exact purpose of predicting class label which can be done in raw format.

I would really like to know the difference between them and also different procedures that I can follow.